# form_for remote not refreshing page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup my page to add links from the home page.  It updates the link in the DB but doesn't refresh the content.  Here's what I have:

controllers/home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if user_signed_in?
      @new_link = Link.create(:link => params[:email])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js do
        end
     end
  end
end
```

views/home/index.html.haml

```
#home
  = render "shares/home_links"
```

views/shares/_home_links.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for Link.new, :remote => true do |f|
  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name, :required => true, :autofocus => true
    = f.input :url, :required => true
    = f.collection_select :category_id, Category.where(:user_id => current_user.id), :id, :name

  .form-actions
    = f.submit 'Save', :class => 'btn btn-info'
```

views/home/create.js.erb

```
$('#home').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shares/home_links') %>");
```

Firebug console shows

```
POST http://localhost:3000/links 302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://localhost:3000/links/45 200 OK (spinner keeps going and browser is slow until I hit refresh)
```

Terminal Output is:

```
Started POST "/links" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-17 23:25:24 -0800
Processing by LinksController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"KPSpEcdrPf1mWMesKT96UY/j1Wozze30LUlno1npT4A=", "link"=>{"name"=>"localhost:3000", "url"=>"http://localhost:3000/", "category_id"=>"5"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `links` (`category_id`, `created_at`, `name`, `position`, `updated_at`, `url`, `user_id`) VALUES (5, '2012-11-18 07:25:24', 'localhost:3000', NULL, '2012-11-18 07:25:24', 'http://localhost:3000/', 1)
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/links/45
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)


Started GET "/links/45" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-17 23:25:24 -0800
Processing by LinksController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"45"}
  Link Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE `links`.`id` = 45 LIMIT 1
  Rendered links/show.html.haml within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.haml (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.haml (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 22ms (Views: 20.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content isn't being refreshed because of the line `simple_form_for Link.new, ...`. You are instantiating a new link object each time the form renders instead of checking to see whether the instance variable `@new_link` has been set. Try changing it to this:

```
simple_form_for @new_link || Link.new, ...
```

---

EDIT: On second thought, simply replacing the form currently rendered in the browser with a new one may not update the fields, as the browser is managing the internal state of the form. You'll have to manually set the values of the fields with javascript. For example, in create.js.erb:

```
$('#id-for-name-field').val(@new_link.name)
$('#id-for-url-field').val(@new_link.url)
...
```

Comment: I made that change - no difference.  = simple_form_for @new_link || Link.new, :remote => true do |f|

Comment: The result is a list of links in the database - not and update to the current links.  So I need it to refresh the page to display the updated list

Comment: I haven't been able to figure this out - apparently it isn't loading the create.js.erb file because even attempting to trigger an alert it doesn't do anything

Comment: First, try changing `format.js do end` to just `format.js`. Then try calling just `alert('something');` in create.js.erb (comment out all other lines). If there's an error in your js on an ajax call, it will fail silently. Could be what was happening to you.

Comment: I made that change but I don't get the alert message - is it possible it isn't running the create.js.erb file at all?

Comment: I noticed in the log you posted that the ajax call is being routed to `LinksController#create`, not `HomeController#create`. The create action you've shown above should be the one in the `LinksController`.

Comment: how do I send it to the HomeController#create?

Comment: You'd be breaking Rails' MVC conventions by creating a `Link` in a controller other than the `LinksController`. There are cases where this is necessary/acceptable, but I don't think this is one of them. In any case, you can route a `form_for` to a different url by specifying `url: some_path`. You need to define a path to `HomeController#create` in your `routes.rb`.

Comment: ok - I did and got ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: link)  -  So I quit and will just do it the old fashioned way - thanks for your patience :)